# Question on electricity

Tags: electric-current

> In a neon discharge tube $2.8 × 10^{18}$ $\text{Ne}^+$ ions move to the right per second while $1.2 ×10^{18}$ electrons move to the left per second. Therefore, the current in the discharge tube is:
>
> 1. $0.64 A$ towards right
> 2. $0.256 A$ towards right
> 3. $0.64 A$ towards left
> 4. $0.256 A$ towards left
>      Well i tried calculating the net charge but it didn't work out.And i do not know differentiation so i am unabke to do this ques.If anyone knows a non differtiation way, That would really help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics.SE!  Please note that we are [not a homework help site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange), and thus your question is liable to be closed in its present format.  If you were to reword your question, showing your work and with what concept you are struggling, you would be far more likely to receive useful help.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint(s): Current's direction is in direction opposite to negative charges and you can calculate the magnitude by $\frac{dq}{dt}$